# Fares and timings for boating in Kanyakumari

Tags: ferries, fares, south-india, tamil-nadu

I have a plan to visit Kanyakumari in Tamilnadu,India and go boating on the seas there. I want to know about the boating services available in the locality. Any information on timings and fare of boats could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in kanyakumari, if you want to see the normal places like Vivekananda memorial etc, ferry services are available from morning 8 to evening 5 but depends on low tide/high tide and timing changes.

For your personal seeing in the seas, there are very few options there and you need to negotiate everything else from timings to fare etc generally. Last time, I visited Kanyakumari 6 months back, i did not found any place where they take you on personal tours in sea.

Comment: @NithinG do you remember the fare for going to Vivekananda memorial.

Comment: it was cheap..  less than 100 bucks for a return trip.  those were like big ferries. You can get smaller ones with less people but they cost more like 500-700 bucks..